# Is this subset of C compact?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I don't think the set is compact because it isn't closed. I'm not sure how to go about proving it though. I tried the neighborhood definition and couldn't think of a suitable r and then the sequence definition and couldn't come up with a suitable sequence in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{i(\frac {\pi} 2+\frac  1 n)}$  [or $(\cos (\frac {\pi} 2+\frac  1 n)+i\sin (\frac {\pi} 2+\frac  1 n)$] is sequence in this set which tends to $i$. So the set is not closed.

Comment: Is there a way you could explain without Euler's number? We haven't really touched on it yet.

Comment: @Tianna I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you induce the standard topology of $\mathbb{C}$ on the unit circle then singletons are closed. Hence complement of a point is open.

Comment: But is it open in $\mathbb{C}$? No

Comment: Yes not open in C but open in S1